# How change the MongoDB aggregation result output?

Tags: mongodb

With this MongoDB aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection('device1_hour_events').aggregate([    
    { $match: { 'ts_hour' : ISODate('2013-10-11T04:00:00.000Z') } },    
    { $unwind:  '$minutes' },
    { $match: { 'minutes.min': { $gt: -1, $lt: 2 } } },
    { $unwind:  '$minutes.seconds' },
    { $group: { '_id': '$minutes.min', 
                'temp_min': { $min: '$minutes.seconds.temp' },          
                'temp_avg': { $avg: '$minutes.seconds.temp' },
                'temp_max': { $max: '$minutes.seconds.temp' }
              }
    },
    { $sort: { '_id': 1} }
])
```

that produces the following result:

```
/* 1 */
{ 
    "_id": 0,
    "temp_min": 12,
    "temp_avg": 47.25,
    "temp_max": 99
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id": 1,
    "temp_min": 35,
    "temp_avg": 47.67,
    "temp_max": 65
}
```

It's possible to obtain maybe with $project the following output:

```
{ 
  "_id": [0, 1], 
  "temp_min": [12, 35],
  "temp_avg": [47.25, 47.67],
  "temp_max": [99, 65]
}
```

Comment: yes, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/, then https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/#exp._S_reverseArray

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'm just starting with MongoDB... I'll have a deeper look in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) for each field :

```
{
    $group: {
        '_id': 0,
        '_ids': { $push: '$_id' },
        'temp_min': { $push: '$temp_min' },
        'temp_avg': { $push: '$temp_avg' },
        'temp_max': { $push: '$temp_max' }
    }
}
```